# Read a given file's attributes

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, tasm, dosbox

I have a task in which they give me the path to a file and I have to print all the attributes of that file...

So far all what I have found on the internet is about writing/reading from a file, but this does not help a bit.

EDIT: It has to be done in assembly language
EDIT2: I'm using windows 7 x64, but all my programs are compiled using TASM, TLINK and I'm using Turbo Debugger for debuggin

Comment: Why did you tag this with assembly? Do you have to implement a file system metadata reader? For which file system? What have you tried?

Comment: I edited. I have to do this in assembly and all of they possible attributes.
So far I've tried nothing, because it's the first time I use files in assembly.

Comment: What processor? What operating system? MS-DOS? Linux? OS/X? Other? 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit?

Comment: So DOSBOX/TASM suggests you are likely writing 16-bit MS-DOS programs

Comment: One of the Best DOS/BIOS resources is [Ralph Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm). In particular you'll be interested in [DOS Int 21h routines](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) but specifically [Get File Attributes](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2802.htm) and the bit fields are defined [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2803.htm#Table1420)

Comment: Michael Petch that's what I was looking for ! Thanks! Could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this seems to be homework/assignment related I'm going to direct you to the resources and Interrupt information that you'll need to perform the task, without writing actual code.

- One of the best places for all thing MS-DOS/BIOS related is [Ralph Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm)
- When dealing with DOS and Files most of the routines of interest will likely be the [DOS Int 21h functions](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm)
- In particular you'll probably want to use DOS's [*Int 21h/AX=4300h* Get File Attributes](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2802.htm) function.

  > ```
  > AX = 4300h
  > DS:DX -> ASCIZ filename
  >
  > Return:
  > CF clear if successful
  > CX = file attributes (see #01420)
  > AX = CX (DR DOS 5.0)
  > CF set on error
  > AX = error code (01h,02h,03h,05h) (see #01680 at AH=59h)
  > ```

  You will also find the [file attribute bits](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2803.htm#Table1420)

  > ```
  > Bit(s)  Description     (Table 01420)
  > 7      shareable (Novell NetWare)
  >        pending deleted files (Novell DOS, OpenDOS)
  > 6      unused
  > 5      archive
  > 4      directory
  > 3      volume label.
  >        Execute-only (Novell NetWare)
  > 2      system
  > 1      hidden
  > 0      read-only
  > ```